# Filtering dataframe rows from dynamic variables within shiny

Tags: r, shiny, subset

I'm writing a shiny function that takes a dataset and generates UI components based upon the presence of design variables (factors) and response variables (numeric).

I would like to have a checkbox input to hide/show all of the variables in the app (the `design` UI element) and also be able to filter out particular rows based upon the levels of the design factors. Since the number of factors in a dataset is unknown, this has to be generated generically.

Within the function, before `ui` and `server` are defined, I find all of the factor variables and generate the relevant parameters for `checkboxGroupInputs` and then in `ui` use `lapply` and `do.call` to add them to the interface. However, I now need to use them to filter the rows and I'm not sure how to do so.

I've prepared a MWE to illustrate:

```
data(iris)
iris$Species2 <- iris$Species

filterex <- function(data = NULL){
  library(shiny)

  # Get design variables (factors) and response variables:
  dvars <- names(which(sapply(data, class) == "factor"))
  rvars <- names(which(sapply(data, class) != "factor"))

  # Generate inputs for all design factor filters:
  num_filters <- length(dvars)
  filters <- list()
  for (i in 1:num_filters){
    filt <- dvars[[i]]
    filters[[i]] <- list(inputId = filt, label = filt,
                         choices = levels(data[[filt]]),
                         selected = levels(data[[filt]]))
  }

  ## UI #############################
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Dynamic filtering example"),
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "design", label = "Design Variables",
                         choices = dvars, selected = dvars),
      # Add filter checkboxes:
  lapply(filters, do.call, what = checkboxGroupInput)),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("data"))
  )

  ## SERVER #########################
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    # SUBSET DESIGN COLUMNS BASED UPON INPUTS:
    dat_subset <- reactive({
      df <- data[, c(input$design, rvars), drop = FALSE]
      # NEED TO INCORPORATE CODE TO SUBSET ROWS HERE
      return(df)
    })

    output$data <- renderDataTable({
      dat_subset()
      })
  }
  runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
}

filterex(iris)
```

My issues are:

1. [**SOLVED**] Even though it appears the filter checkboxes are being created (lines 11:19), I cannot get them to be included in the app as expected.
2. Once they are added, I'm not sure how to utilize them to filter the rows as needed around line 40 (e.g., should be able to uncheck `setosa` from `Species` to hide those rows).

Any advice would be really appreciated! I've looked at many other threads, but all the solutions I've come across are tailored for a particular dataset (so the number and names of the variables are known a priori).

Comment: One issue is the `for()` loop inside `sidebarPanel()`. I've noticed that if I change `checkboxGroupInput` in the first for loop to `list()`, and replace the second for loop with `do.call(checkboxGroupInput, filters[[1]])`, I can get the factor levels to render... but only for the first variable.

Comment: OK, I think I've solved issue #1 with using `lapply(filters, do.call, what = checkboxGroupInput)` in the `ui`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your arrived solution, consider `lapply` over `for` loops in building *filters* and dynamic subsetting:

```
filterex <- function(data = NULL){

  # Get design variables (factors) and response variables:
  dvars <- names(which(sapply(data, class) == "factor"))
  rvars <- names(which(sapply(data, class) != "factor"))

  # Generate inputs for all design factor filters:
  filters <- lapply(dvars, function(d) {
    list(inputId = d, label = d,
         choices = levels(data[[d]]),
         selected = levels(data[[d]]))
  })

  ## UI #############################
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Dynamic filtering example"),
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "design", label = "Design Variables",
                         choices = dvars, selected = dvars),
      # Add filter checkboxes:
      lapply(filters, do.call, what = checkboxGroupInput)),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("data"))
  )

  ## SERVER #########################
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    # SUBSET DESIGN COLUMNS BASED UPON INPUTS:
    dat_subset <- reactive({
      df <- data[, c(input$design, rvars), drop = FALSE]

      # DF SUBSET LIST
      dfs <- lapply(dvars, function(d) {
        df[df[[d]] %in% input[[d]],]
      })
      # ROW BIND ALL DFs
      df <- do.call(rbind, dfs) 
      return(df)
    })

    output$data <- renderDataTable({
      dat_subset()
    })
  }
  runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
}

filterex(iris)
```

Comment: That's great! I wasn't very confident with my use of `lapply()` in this context, but that makes sense. Thanks! One further modification/request: do you see any easy way to link the filters to their being checked under design variables? (e.g., if we uncheck Species2 from "Design Variables", have that checkboxInput() disappear from the UI)

Comment: OK, I've been tinkering with it and had the following observations: 1) `rbind()` isn't the right call for joining the dataframes, since this takes the 150 rows and returns a dataframe with 300 rows ;) -- I've updated this to a `merge()` call. 2) I've figured out a way to have the filters added dynamically using `uiOutput()`. I've updated my code in the other answer below - but I had to resort to a `for()` loop and 2 `if()`s. The filters work *except* when I hide a design factor. Any ideas for cleaning this up and fixing this behaviour?

Comment: I fixed the issue, so now it is just ugly ;)

Comment: First, nothing wrong with `for`, I used `lapply` since it returns a list. But I am not seeing how `merge` (wide dataset) works over `rbind` (long dataset) especially since these row bind *subsetted* data frames. However, like you did the *dfList* must be conditioned on selected unhid column values. I'll update when back on CPU.

Comment: When I ran the code earlier, the first element of the list was subsetted properly (e.g., removing one flower type gave a df with 100 rows), but then the second filter returned the full dataset (150 rows), and so the overall outcome was a df with 250 rows, after being row bound. So in the code below, I added an ID variable, so `merge` will only return the rows across all of the dataframes that match. I believe this should work if there are many (more than the 2 here) design factors used for the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a better way of doing this, I would love to hear it but I have a working prototype! This can show/hide the design variables and filter the rows based upon the boxes that are checked/unchecked. Further, the UI elements for the filters are added/hidden based upon the design selection :)

```
filterex <- function(data = NULL){

  # Get design variables (factors) and response variables:
  dvars <- names(which(sapply(data, class) == "factor"))
  rvars <- names(which(sapply(data, class) != "factor"))
  data$internalid <- 1:nrow(data)

  ## UI #############################
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Dynamic filtering example"),
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "design", label = "Design Variables",
                         choices = dvars, selected = dvars),
      uiOutput("filters")),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("data"))
  )

  ## SERVER #########################
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    # Determine checkboxes:
    output$filters <- renderUI({
      filters <- lapply(dvars[dvars == input$design], function(d) {
        list(inputId = d, label = d,
             choices = levels(data[[d]]),
             selected = levels(data[[d]]))
      })
      lapply(filters, do.call, what = checkboxGroupInput)
    })

    # GENERATE REDUCED DATA TABLE:
    dat_subset <- reactive({
      # SUBSET DATA BY DESIGN INPUTS
      df <- data[, c(input$design, rvars, "internalid"), drop = FALSE]

      # SUBSET DATA BY ROWS AND MERGE
      for (i in 1:length(input$design)){
        if(!is.null(input[[input$design[[i]]]])){
          dfs <- lapply(input$design, function(d) {
            df[df[[d]] %in% input[[d]],]
          })
          if (length(dfs) > 1){
            df <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=FALSE), dfs) 
          } else df <- dfs[[1]]
        }        
      }
      return(df)
    })

    output$data <- renderDataTable({
      dat_subset()[,c(input$design, rvars)]
    })
  }
  runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
}

data(iris)
iris$Species2 <- iris$Species
filterex(iris)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `tidyverse`

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

filterex <- function(data = NULL) {
    i1 <-  data %>%
                 summarise_all(is.factor) %>%
                 unlist()
    dvars <- i1 %>%
                names(.)[.]
    rvars <- i1 %>%
                 `!` %>%
                 names(.)[.]

   filters <-dvars %>% 
                map(~list(inputId = ., 
                          label = ., 
                          choices = levels(data[[.]]), 
                          selected = levels(data[[.]])))




  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Dynamic filtering example"),
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "design",
                          label = "Design Variables",
                          choices = dvars,
                          selected = dvars),
                          map(filters, ~do.call(what = checkboxGroupInput, .))),
                          mainPanel(dataTableOutput("data"))
    )



  server = function(input, output, session) {

    dat_subset <- reactive({
        df <-  data %>%
                 select(input$design, rvars) 
        dvars %>% 
              map2_df(list(df), ~.y  %>%
                        filter_at(.x, all_vars(. %in% input[[.x]])))



    })  
    output$data <- renderDataTable({
              dat_subset()
      })

    }

  runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
    }
```

Using the function on 'iris'

```
filterex(iris)
```

Output got is

[image]